# Newbie to PouchDB - Couple of questions

Tags: pouchdb

Could you please let me know your inputs on below questions (all related to IndexedDB as underlying database layer):

1. When I delete a document from the PouchDB, I can still see its data in my IndexedDB. Although there is some attribute to identify that this document is deleted, but still it is present inside DB, so it is unnecessarily occupying space. Isn't it?
2. I specify DB name as "ABC", but when I look into IndexedDB then my DB name is prefixed with "*pouch*". Am i missing anything?
3. How I can see all the existing document (not including deleted documents) inside my IndexedDB? I found some "document-store" but it is not listing real document data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, but that's how CouchDB works. For example, it is necessary to have these docs so a replication from an outdated source don't come up with that same document that was deleted and get it recreated in your Pouch.
2. What do you expected? This is good for avoiding conflicts with other uses of IndexedDB. But you can always recompile PouchDB yourself removing that hardcoded `__pouch_`.
3. `yourpouch.allDocs({include_docs: true})` should do the job. If you're talking about Developer Tools, I don't know, maybe you should try https://github.com/marten-de-vries/pouchdb-fauxton-chrome-extension

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, this is what compaction is for: http://pouchdb.com/guides/compact-and-destroy.html
2. Nope, it's supposed to be prefixed. We do that to avoid clashing with any other possible IndexedDBs.
3. It sounds like what you really want is a better debugger. I recommend the PouchDB Inspector plugin, details are here: http://pouchdb.com/guides/databases.html

Comment: I tried the compaction mode, but I can still see the reference and details of the deleted document. I used `code`var dbCompact1 = new PouchDB('mydbCompact1', {auto_compaction: true});`code` to create database in compaction mode. Used `code`dbCompact1.put({
  _id: 'VC12342',
  JOB_ID: 'VC12342',
  DATA: 'DataVC12342'
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
}); `code` to put a document. And used something like `code` dbCompact1.get("VC12342").then(function(doc) {
  return dbCompact1.remove(doc);
}) `code` to delete doc.

Comment: In "by-sequence" and "document-store" I can see the revision details of those documents. For us, maintaining these revision numbers is also unnecessary storage waste, and we want to get rid of these as well. If a document is deleted then we completely want to get rid of all the details of the deleted document. Please let me know your inputs.

Comment: That's the `purge()` feature; it's not implemented yet: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/802